# Hibernate: Storing an fixed length array in one database table row

Tags: mysql, arrays, hibernate

I have been trying to find a solution to store a fixed length array as a property of an object using hibernate in the same DB table as the object not using a BLOB for the array.

I currently have a class ProductionQCSession which looks like

```
@Entity
public class ProductionQCSession extends IdEntity {

    private Long id;
    private Float velocity;
    private Float velocityTarget;
    private Float[] velocityProfile;

    public ProductionQCSession() {
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    public Float getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }

    public void setVelocity(Float velocity) {
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    @Basic
    public Float[] getVelocityProfile() {
        return velocityProfile;
    }

    public void setVelocityProfile(Float[] velocityProfile) {
        this.velocityProfile = velocityProfile;
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like the DB structure to be

```
id|velocity|VPValue0|VPValue1|VPValue2|VPValue3|...    
21|     2.1|     0.1|     0.2|    -0.1|     0.3|...
```

I know with a high certainty that we always have 15 items in the velocityProfile array and those values as just as much properties of the object as any other property therefore I think it makes sense to add them to the database table schema, if it's possible. I would prefer to have it this way as it would be easy to get a overview of the data just doing a raw table print.

The current code just stores the array data as a BLOB.

I have looked http://ndpsoftware.com/HibernateMappingCheatSheet.html mapping cheat sheet, but could not seem to find any good solution.

I'm I just trying to do something nobody else would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you're trying to have a multi-value field, which is not a relational database concept.  A normalized solution would put those into a child table, which Hibernate would let you access directly from the parent row (and return it as a collection).

If you are adamant that it should be in a single table, then you'll need to create 15 individual columns....and hope that in the future you don't suddenly need 16.

Comment: Since the 15 individual columns relate to a physical aspect of a mass manufactured component, it's very unlikely that it will change. But as you propose I decided to follow the standard solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being using the standardised method of using a child table even though it makes the data analysis slightly more complicated. The following code was used.

```
        @ElementCollection
        @CollectionTable(name ="QCVelocityProfile")
        public List<Float> getVelocityProfile() {
            return velocityProfile;
        }

        public void setVelocityProfile(List<Float> velocityProfile) {
            this.velocityProfile = velocityProfile;
        }
```